# AudioInputStream to Buffer

Tags: java

I am working on a web application wherein I am recording sound from my microphone using a [flash plugin](http://www.sajithmr.me/jrecorder/example1.html). After the recording I can upload the recorded file to the server. Plz see the code below:

```
            // Get the input stream
            InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
            InputStream bufferedIn = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(bufferedIn);

            // Declare the new format to convert to
            AudioFormat audioFormat =  new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed, bigEndian);

            // Convert the format and return the new audio input stream
            ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFormat, ais);
```

Now, after this conversion I want to save the audio data from ais into a buffer and upload it to DB.

How do I do that? Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 0):

`AudioInputStream` extends `InputStream`, so you can use it directly to store to the database. When using JDBC, you could use:

```
ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(audioFormat, ais);
PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement("insert into data values(?, ?)");
prep.setInt(1, 1);
prep.setBinaryStream(2, ais);
```

Please note `setBinaryStream` without length parameter is only available in Java 6 and newer. Some databases may not support it.